# Pyeda module not accessible

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, pyeda

I'm attempting to make use of PyEDA, and as such I downloaded the library and attempted to use it. For reference, I am using VSCode. When I attempt to run the program, I receive the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyeda'

Would anyone have any ideas as to the cause of this?

Comment: How did you install pyeda?

Comment: @S.B Using Ubuntu, I ran "python3 -m install pip pyeda"

Comment: If it was successful, it probably means you're installing the package in one interpreter and running your script with another.

Comment: How can I check which interpreter it was installed to?

Comment: `import sys;print(sys.executable)` gives you the path of the interpreter which currently runs your script. `pip -V` usually tells you the location in which the package is going to be installed. What I suggest you to do so is to create a virtual environment first, then activate it, then install that package into that environment. Also in order to run your script with that environment, make sure it's activated and then run your script. You shouldn't encounter any problem anymore.